# Eevee. Volumetric Lighting doesn't appear. Regardless of settings

Tags: lighting, eevee-render-engine

Kinda Feel like I'm going crazy, I've tried everything from coping node setups 1 to 1 to outright downloading files with volumetric fog  already set up. Even in the files I downloaded(Which indeed DO have volumetric fog in them) It still doesn't show up. I did check multiple times and volumetric lighting and shadows IS enabled in the render settings.

This is the file I downloaded and here is out it appears when it is rendering properly https://youtu.be/HZYWRso8iAk?t=213

And here is how it looks on my system:

[image]